# django orm: Check if obj is in queryset

Tags: django, orm, contains

How can I check whether an obj is in a queryset or not?

I tried this:

```
self.assertIn(obj, list(MyModel.objects.filter(...))
```

But it does not work in my case.

```
AssertionError: <MyModel 137 'unclassified'> not found in 
[<MyModel 1676 'foo'>, ..., <MyModel 137 'unclassified'>, ...]
```

I don't understand it, since it is in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be `MyModel.objects.filter(...)`. If you omit the `.objects`, you should've gotten a different error, so I'm assuming you did include it but just forgot it in the question.

If `obj` is actually in the `QuerySet` returned, what you did should have worked as Django model instances provides an equal comparator which compares both the type and the primary key. `list()` is not required around the `QuerySet`, though it should still work if you used it.

From the [Django 1.5 source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/db/models/base.py#L436-L437):

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self._get_pk_val() == other._get_pk_val()
```

If it still doesn't work, there are a few possible causes:

1. The type doesn't match. In this case, it doesn't matter even if the object pk exists in the QuerySet's object pks. (You cannot compare apples to oranges)
2. There is no such object in the database (i.e. it hasn't been saved yet)
3. The type matches but the object is not in the QuerySet (i.e. filtered out)
4. You overrode the `__eq__` method and did something weird. Or you overrode the default manager `.objects` with some custom filter. This scenario is outside the scope of this answer and if you did this, you should probably know how to fix it.

To help you diagnose which is the case, try this:

```
self.assertTrue(isinstance(obj, MyModel))
# 1. If it fails here, your object is an incorrect type

# Warning: the following tests can be very slow if you have a lot of data

self.assertIn(obj.pk, MyModel.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True))
# 2. If it fails here, the object doesn't exist in the database

self.assertIn(obj.pk, MyModel.objects.filter(...).values_list('pk', flat=True))
# 3. If it fails here, the object did not pass your filter conditions.

self.assertIn(obj, MyModel.objects.filter(...))
# 4. If it fails here, you probably messed with the Django ORM internals. Tsk tsk.
```

Comment: The missing "object" was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @guettli Did you try the assertions? Did it fail on any of them?

Comment: The broken code was refactored, and works now. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
self.assertTrue(MyModel.filter(...).filter(pk=obj.pk).exists())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with, note the `.all()`

```
queryset_result = MyModel.filter(...).all()

if obj in  queryset_result:
    //obj is in the queryset
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your solution. Do you think that adding `.all()` changes the behaviour? I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

The "in" fails because the objects aren't actually equal, as equality is object identity by default. If you want "in" to work, you'd have to implement `__eq__` accordingly on your model.

If you don't want to do that, you can check by comparing the pk, like so

```
self.assertIn(obj.pk, [o.pk for o in MyModel.filter(...)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think This is very simple way get to find out object present in queryset or not.

First Example:

```
obj_list = MyModel.filter(...)
if obj in obj_list:
    print "obj in queryset"
else:
    print "not in queryset"
```

Second Example:

```
obj_list = MyModel.filter(...)

try:
   obj_list.get(pk=obj.id)
except:
   # If try get success obj is present in query set else your this except get executed.
```